# Checking undefined value

Tags: javascript

We can check whether a variable `a` is undefined using:

```
if(typeof(a)!=="undefined"){
   console.log("a is not undefined");
}
```

but can the following simple checking achieve the same purpose?

```
if(!a){
   console.log("a is not undefined");
}
```

Comment: If `a` is not defined anywhere, second case will throw error..

Comment: @RayonDabren in both cases you get an exception, if `a` is not declared.

Comment: @NinaScholz, I disagree... Anything to back your statement ?

Comment: @RayonDabre They are talking about the reference error.

Comment: [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operates without parenthesis.

Comment: @NinaScholz, https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/7k8h76Lq/ and with `strict mode` => https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/7k8h76Lq/1/

Comment: it depends on strict mode. is set, then it throws an error; if not, then not.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, `typeof` will never throe `Reference error` except `typeof var` or `typeof for` etc..

Answer (score 0):

```
(typeof value !== "undefined")
//or
(value != "")
//or
(value != "undefined")
```

Because remember this things in Js undefined,null,0 all of these are a object
and it same that why we are facing this problem in case of so care this things.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends if `a` has been declared at that moment(by using `var` or as a parameter in a function), you can do without `typeof`:

```
//this produces a log
testOptParam();
//note that the following will have the same result
testOptParam(0);
//but this won't produce log
testOptParam("text...");

function testOptParam(optionalParam){
   if(!optionalParam){
      console.log("optionalParam IS undefined...or null or false or 0");
   }
}
```

...but as mentioned in the code, the behaviour is the same if your variable is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) (undefined but also null or equals to false or 0 or '').

Furthermore, your code can throw an exception if your variable hasn't been declared yet.

This is why if you want to specifically check if a value is undefined is to use the `typeof` solution.